# Implementation of binary search

Tags: python, beginner, binary-search, divide-and-conquer

I am new to the divide and conquer paradigm.  I wanted to verify that there's nothing wrong with this implementation of binary search.

I ran it a few times and it does print the correct result, but I also wanted a sanity check and any possible improvements.

```
def search(array, item):

    if len(array) == 1:
        if array[0] == item:
            return 1
        return 0

    mid = len(array) // 2
    x = array[:mid]
    y = array[mid:]

    found = []

    found.append(search(x, item))
    found.append(search(y, item))

    for elm in found:
        if elm ==  1:
            return True

    return False


print(search([1,2,3,4], 8))
print(search([1,2,3,4], 3))
```

Also, the running time of this is \$O(n log(n))\$, correct? \$O(log(n))\$ being the recursion and \$O(n)\$ being the loop that checks the `result` list.

Comment: this ... you do know that the time complexity of a binary search should be just \$O(\log(n))\$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks *almost* correct. But it can be improved.

#### Bug

What will happen if the input array is empty? Stack overflow.

#### Boolean values

Why return 1 for true and 0 for false instead of using boolean values?

> ```
> if array[0] == item:
>     return 1
> return 0
> ```

In fact you could return the result of the boolean expression directly:

```
return array[0] == item
```

Similarly, what's happening here?

> ```
> found = []
>
> found.append(search(x, item))
> found.append(search(y, item))
>
> for elm in found:
>     if elm ==  1:
>         return True
>
> return False
> ```

You append 0-1 values into `found`. If `found` contains a 1, return `True`,
otherwise return `False`. All this could be written on a single line:

```
return search(left, item) or search(right, item)
```

I also renamed the meaningless `x` and `y` to `left` and `right`.

#### Use doctests

[Doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) are awesome. They are easy to write and execute and can greatly increase your confidence in your code and make it possible to refactor the code safely. For example:

```
def search(array, item):
    """
    >>> search([], 1)
    False

    >>> search([1,2,3,4], 8)
    False

    >>> search([1,2,3,4], 0)
    False

    >>> search([1,2,3,5], 4)
    False

    >>> search([1,2,3,5], 3)
    True

    >>> search([1,2,3,5], 5)
    True

    >>> search([1,2,3,5], 1)
    True

    """

    if not array:
        return False

    if len(array) == 1:
        return array[0] == item

    mid = len(array) // 2
    left = array[:mid]
    right = array[mid:]

    return search(left, item) or search(right, item)
```

You can run this with `python -m doctest script.py`.
If any of the test cases fails, you'll get a nice report (otherwise no output).